# My ASP.NET MVC app takes me back to the login page when I access the home controller even though I'm logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

When I log in as a user, and type the `url http://localhost:50562/Home/Index` into the address bar, the browser takes me to the login page, which is my home page, but the funny thing is that the message "welcome, user!" and Logout link are still there in the upper right corner. When I click on the other links in the nav bar, the session continues normally, meaning, I was never logged out.

Can someone tell me how to configure the routing engine to take me to another page when I access the Home controller while being logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, but it seems that the project had a `SessionObject` class all along, which was handled by the controller. I am not the original author of the project, so it took me a while to figure it out. I was tasked to give it some additional features and bugfixes.

I ran into the method:

```
#region getSessionObject()
    protected SessionObject getSessionObject() {
        SessionObject loReturnValue = null;

        if (Session[SessionObject.SESSION_CONSTANT] != null)
            loReturnValue = (SessionObject) Session[SessionObject.SESSION_CONSTANT];

        return loReturnValue;
    }
```

It was all I needed to call in the index action of my home controller to check whether the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by modifying the POST method for Login in the Account Controller (assuming you are using MVC 4 and the Simple Membership it uses).

```
 // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

       ...
    }
```

You can set the routing in a few ways.

1. return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Home"); ... where Profile is a Controller
2. return View(returnUrl); ... where you have set and assigned the variable in your method
3. or retain as above with RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing happens because the user cookie isn't read until after the redirect to the home page is initiated. The best way to initialize your membership provider when users may enter on different pages is to use a global filter.

You can add this functionality for the SimpleMembership provider in the RegisterGlobalFilters method in the FilterConfig class in the App_Start folder

```
filters.Add(new YourAppNameSpace.Filters.InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute());
```

Using a filter keeps you from having to repeat yourself with decorators all over your controller classes. It's easy to overlook adding decorators and, when they aren't there, your site will have unexpected bugs.